# Installshield Setup.Rul - Starting dependant services using ServiceStartService/LaunchAppAndWait

Tags: service, installshield

I need your help.

I am maintaining an old Installshield Setup.Rul that was written by a different team.
The .exe starts a set of Custom Services.

Now I have a requirement where in I need to start a set of services, based on few dependency criteria, when the .exe created using installshield is run.
Here is the sample code I have form Setup.Rul.

```
    sApp1 = "sc";
    sParam = "failure ASER reset= 0 actions= restart/100000";
    LaunchAppAndWait (sApp1, sParam, WAIT);
    sParam = "failure BSER reset= 0 actions= restart/100000";
    LaunchAppAndWait (sApp1, sParam, WAIT);
    sParam = "failure CSER reset= 0 actions= restart/100000";
    LaunchAppAndWait (sApp1, sParam, WAIT);
    sParam = "failure DSER reset= 0 actions= restart/100000";
    LaunchAppAndWait (sApp1, sParam, WAIT);
    ServiceStartService("ASER", "");  
    ServiceStartService("BSER", "");  
    ServiceStartService("CSER", ""); 
    ServiceStartService("DSER", "");
```

Now the requirement is that, BSER is dependant on ASER, in the sense, BSER should wait till ASER is fully started, & then only be started.
And DSER should wait till CSER & DSER are fully started, & then only be started.

However, I did see the dependencies section in this document
http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/componentcontrolnt.htm
But I am not able to figure out the correct syntax.

Can any of you please help.

Thank you.

Prashant.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have this working yet try changing WAIT to LAAW_OPTION_WAIT,  If this is a Basic MSI project you find it easier to do this with Services on the System Configuration tab instead of with a CA.